# @Inject returns null

Tags: java, java-ee-6, weblogic11g

Why does @Inject annotation return always null on every point of my webapp?

I'm using jdk8, maven and weblogic 10.3.6 for deployment.

on my pom.xml is specified that the application must be compiled for java 6.

This is an example:

```
public class QuartzListener implements ServletContextListener {
    Scheduler scheduler = null;

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Inject private JobFactoryImpl jobFactory;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContext) {
        System.out.println("Hello!");

        try {
            scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            scheduler.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
            scheduler.start();
            ...
            ...
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContext) {
        System.out.println("Bye Bye!");
    }
}


@LocalBean
public class JobFactoryImpl implements JobFactory {

    @Inject
    private Instance<Job> jobs;

    @Override
    public Job newJob(TriggerFiredBundle triggerFiredBundle, Scheduler scheduler) throws SchedulerException {
        things...
    }
}
```

I've an exception due to jobFactory is null on "scheduler.setJobFactory(jobFactory);"

beans.xml is in WEB-INF folder

this is my web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.5"  
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>app-name</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>${Path}/log4j.properties </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.blabla.quartz.QuartzListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener> 
        <listener-class>com.blabla.listener.PropertiesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        ...
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <resource-ref>
        ...
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

Edit
This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.blabla</groupId>
    <artifactId>cps</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>appname</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.enterprise/cdi-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.oracle</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Quartz 2.2.1 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ejb/javax.ejb-api -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc14 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <!-- Set war name -->
        <finalName>war-name</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

NB: same code, in weblogic 12.1.3, works

Comment: Misunderstood what you said

Comment: "@Inject private JobFactoryImpl jobFactory;" doesn't work.
i'm asking why Inject annotation doesn't return a JobFactoryImpl instance istead of null

Comment: Which injection framework do you use?

Comment: @Innet, please try annotating your class as a singleton. LocalBeans are a no-interface view

Comment: @Miles Done, but nothing changes. Inject annotation doesn't work even on my controller and service classes... :<

Comment: Edit: i added my pom.xml

Comment: Looks like `QuartzListener` is not scanned by CDI. Did you put `bean-discovery-mode="all"` in beans.xml? Otherwise not annotated beans will not be scanned by CDI.

Comment: This is my beans.xml now:
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>

But no way, injection still returns null

Comment: Weblogic 10.3.6 does not come with CDI implementation as it is a Java EE 5 server (CDI is a Java EE 6 API).

Comment: @Innet, you have the cdi-api in your POM, but there is no implementation on WebSphere. Try adding weld (or another of your choice). I have seen guides on this before

Comment: @Innet : already tried to make Weld (CDI Implementation) working on WLS10.3.6 but encounter many problems so I switched to WLS 12C. Why do you need to make it work on 10.3.6?

Comment: Boss wants 10.3.6 :)
Anyway i solved introducing Spring. Now i'm able to use @Autowired